# How to save an exception and throw it later

Tags: c++, exception

Say I want to create an exception object, but throw it a bit later. My use case is that the exception is generated in a thread, but I need to actually throw it from my main thread (because there's nobody to catch it in the child thread)

```
using namespace std;

runtime_error *ex = nullptr;

thread myThread( [&ex]{
    if (something_went_wrong) {
        ex = new runtime_error("Something went wrong");
        return;
    }
} );

myThread.join();
if (ex != nullptr) {
    throw *ex;
}
```

For what it's worth, the compiler seems happy with this, but I can see that it's a resource leak at best. Is there a right way to do this?

Comment: This is already something `std::promise` supports. Rather than managing threads and global state between them, use `std::future` (or a better third-party one) to make the thread a logical task with a "return value". Then manual threads also become only one implementation, with others being a thread pool, coroutines, or some other higher-level construct.

Comment: Make `ex` into a `std::unique_ptr<runtime_error>`. That'll fix the memory leak.

Comment: See [`std::exception_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr), [`std::current_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception) and associated features.

Comment: @chris unfortunately, this is existing code I can't refactor.

Comment: Using `*ex` will prevent any polymorphism in your exceptions. The exception thrown will always be a `runtime_error` regardless of the exception's dynamic type, and you may encounter problems related to object slicing.

Comment: @François Andrieux I'm ok with that, the exception I'm catching is always one specific exception.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo Your suggestion of using `unique_ptr` seems to work just fine; make it an answer and I'll accept it. I did a little searching and have confirmed that unique_ptr goes out of scope and deletes its payload normally, even during an exception.

Comment: @EdwardFalk If you were unsure that `unique_ptr` correctly deleting the object in case of exceptions, then you must not be familiar with RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization). This is a fundamental concept on which modern C++ is designed, and I recommend reading about it here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii

Comment: I'm very familiar with RAII, but I wasn't quite positive that throwing an exception wouldn't short-circuit it. I see that it doesn't, so we're good.

Comment: Slightly meta: it's worth noting that there's no "right" way to bail out of a thread via exception. Exiting a thread by _any_ means other than a normal return risks resource leaks. Only do it when you're dead certain this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::exception_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr) is the C++ facility to store exceptions. It can usually avoid an extra allocation.

```cpp
std::exception_ptr ex = nullptr;

std::thread myThread( [&ex]{
    if (something_went_wrong) {
        ex = std::make_exception_ptr(std::runtime_error("Something went wrong"));
        return;
    }
} );

myThread.join();
if (ex != nullptr) {
    std::rethrow_exception(ex);
}
```

And since it can store any type of exception, you can store anything that could be thrown in the thread by wrapping the lambda like:

```cpp
std::thread myThread( [&ex]{
    try {
        // do things
    } catch (...) {
        ex = std::current_exception();
    }
} );
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a [`std::optional<std::runtime_error>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

```cpp
std::optional<std::runtime_error> ex;

std::thread myThread( [&ex]{
    if (something_went_wrong) {
        ex.emplace("Something went wrong");
        return;
    }
} );

myThread.join();
if (ex) {
    throw *ex;
}
```

Which won't leak since you don't dynamically allocate

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. `std::current_exception()` is actually how I did it in an earlier incarnation of this problem. I hadn't thought about using `emplace()` to avoid the allocation; let me give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution I found, but I liked the unique_ptr solution better. Writing it here for completeness:

```
using namespace std;

runtime_error *ex = nullptr;

thread myThread( [&ex]{
    if (something_went_wrong) {
        ex = new runtime_error("Something went wrong");
        return;
    }
} );

myThread.join();
if (ex != nullptr) {
    runtime_error e2 = *ex;
    delete ex;
    throw e2;
}
```